# Return value of contract function in web3 is array, not uint

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am working on the ethernaut game to learn about solidity and the ethereum ecosystem.  I solved the Fallback problem, but don't understand the interaction below.

The basic question is: the contract has a function that returns a uint, the interaction shows it as returning an array.  Why?  And how do I map the array to the uint?

The relevant part of the contract is

```
  function contribute() public payable {
    require(msg.value < 0.001 ether);
    contributions[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    if(contributions[msg.sender] > contributions[owner]) {
      owner = msg.sender;
    }
  }

  function getContribution() public view returns (uint) {
    return contributions[msg.sender];
  }
```

The interaction is (addresses and tx ids edited out, though I think b/c it is the testnet there is little reason to)

```
>> await contract.getContribution()
Object { negative: 0, words: (2) […], length: 1, red: null }
length: 1
negative: 0
red: null
words: Array [ 0, <1 empty slot> ]
0: 0
length: 2
​​...
>> await contract.contribute({from: "0x<XXX>", value: web3.utils.toWei('0.0001', 'ether')})
Object { tx: "0x<XXX>", receipt: {…}, logs: [] }

>> await contract.getContribution()
Object { negative: 0, words: (3) […], length: 2, red: null }
length: 2
negative: 0
red: null
words: Array(3) [ 8011776, 1490116, <1 empty slot> ]
0: 8011776
1: 1490116
length: 3
​​...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> Number(await contract.getContribution())
```

Comment: I see.  The local contract doesn't know the return type, and interprets it as an array.  Reading that data appropriately (with Number()) does get me the expected value.